# read the file and assign the values to another file

Tags: shell-script, shell

I want to read the file and assign the values to variables whic is in another file using shell script.

For example I have file as "myconf"

```
cli="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/bin/rhq-cli.sh"
user="rhqadmin"
passwd="janre"
file1="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/agentresourceid.js"
file2="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/agentresourceid"
file3="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/alertresourceid.js"
file4="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/alertresourceid"
file5="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/alertid"
```

and my script in another file as "testconf"

```
$cli -u $user -p $passwd -s $host -f $file3 > $file4
```

I want to get the values for the variables(cli,user etc) from "myconf" file.
Used while loop to read the values it has been assigning the entire line (`cli="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/bin/rhq-cli.sh"`) to $cli.
Need to assign only the values after the field separator(=) to my variable

Example:

`echo $cli`
should print `/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/bin/rhq-cli.sh`
not as `cli="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/bin/rhq-cli.sh"`

I cant change "myconf" file it is predefined one.
Please help on this

Answer (score 4):

#### The Careful Approach

Try:

```
while IFS== read -r var value
do
    value="${value#\"}"
    [ "$var" ] && declare "$var=${value%\"}"
done <myconf
echo "$cli"
```

This produces the output:

```
/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/bin/rhq-cli.sh
```

#### How it works

- `while IFS== read -r var value; do`

  This starts a loop.  It temporarily sets the field separator, `IFS`, to an equal sign, `=`.  It then reads a line and separates the line into the two variables `var` and `value`.  `var` gets assigned to whatever is before the first `=` and `value` gets whatever is after the first `=`.
- `value="${value#\"}"`

  This removes the leading `"` from the value.
- `[ "$var" ] && declare "$var=${value%\"}"`

  If `var` is not empty, in other words, if we have not read an empty line, then assign the variable `$var` to the value `${value%\"}"` where `${value%\"}"` removes the trailing `"` from `$value`.
- `done <myconf`

  This signals the end of the loop and sets the loops input from the file `myconf`.

#### The Trusting Approach

This sources the file `myconf`:

```
. myconf
echo "$cli"
```

This produces the output:

```
/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/bin/rhq-cli.sh
```

Because this approach executes the file `myconf`, it requires you to trust whoever created `myconf`.  If the file `myconf` contains any shell-active characters, the results might not be what you want.

Comment: The idea of setting IFS to `=` is interesting. I take it setting IFS to `=` leaves the line/record separator of `\n` untouched, in other words `read` will still read only a single line a time, another `while` loop will happen, then `read` does another single line etc etc?

Comment: @the_velour_fog Yes, that is right.   Unless the `-d` option is set, `read` will read exactly one line at a time.  `IFS` only affects how word splitting is performed on that line.